# Firestore filtering multiple documents pricing

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

assume that 1000 documents in cities and only has 5 capitals are true. This query returned 5 results. Now my question is, will I be charged for 1000 document reads or 5 document reads for this query (without using .limit())?

```
db.collection("cities").where("capital", "==", true)
.get()
.then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
});
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're charged for the number of documents you read, not the total number in the collection. So if you're only reading 5 documents, you're charged for 5 document reads.

Comment: I found this, "By default, Cloud Firestore retrieves all documents that satisfy the query in ascending order by document ID, but you can order and limit the data returned.", can you explain this statement?

Comment: This is about sort order: whether the results are ascending or descending. It has nothing to do with the number of documents retrieved, and merely says that the default is that you get sorted results in ascending order.